# формируем url в input yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Задача:
есть форма добавления товара в таблицу.
Поля:
`id` `name` `cat_id` `cat_name` `url` `img`
как сделать авто формирование url из имени товара(name)??
поле name на русском языке

Comment: URL и input никак не связаны. Настраивайте ЧПУ для записей из БД.

Comment: @Krafik Покажите формат нужного `url`

Comment: @Streletz
мне нужно, чтобы в зависимости от того, что я введу в поле name, у меня сформировался текст ссылки в другом поле. после этого я добавляю в бд запись.
и уже при рендере пачки товаров, я дергал из бд текст ссылки, куда будет переадресован пользователь сайта, чтобы посмотреть всю инфу по карточке товара.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть же уже давно бихевиор специальный в коробке. Надо в модели добавить его и указать из какого атрибута брать данные и в какой атрибут записывать.

```
use yii\behaviors\SluggableBehavior;

...

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'slugAttribute' => 'url',
        ],
    ];
}
```

В рулсах для поля `url` не забываем ставить `safe`, потому что оно будет заполняться автоматом.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду пробовать

Answer (score 1):

`beforeSave` метод в модели, в нем по своей логике формируйте url.